# How to set a variable to the output of a form's input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Let's say I have the following code, and I want to have N1 and N2 equal the inputs of numberInput1 and numberInput2 respectively. How would I do that?

```js
"use strict";
// Alternative formula: MN = (N1 * (N2 - 2)) + (N1 + (N2 - 1))

N1 = numberInput1;
N2 = numberInput2;

// side number
SN = N1 + (N2 - 1);
// inside number
IN = N1 * (N2 - 2);
// multiplied number
MN = IN + SN;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Multiplication Table Additive Pairs</title>
    <meta name="description" content="calculates the multiplication table's additive pairs">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form
        action="/Kinda Useful Programs/Text-based/Math-based/Calculations/Calculating Multiplication Table Additive Pairs/index.html"
        method="GET">
        <label for="input number">Please enter a number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="input number 1" id="numberInput1" required>
        <input type="text" name="input number 2" id="numberInput2" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `N1 = parseInt(numberInput1.value)`. But you need to run that code in an event listener that runs after the user fills in all the values. You're running it when the page is loaded, before the user has entered anything.

Comment: Do you know why people use strict? That's invalid JS you got there in strict mode.

Comment: I've put this in but it still doesn't work. it returns NaN for all of them.
`"use strict";
// Alternative formula: MN = (N1 * (N2 - 2)) + (N1 + (N2 - 1))
function createVariables() {
    const N1 = parseInt(numberInput1.value);
    const N2 = parseInt(numberInput2.value);

    // side number
    const SN = N1 + (N2 - 1);
    // inside number
    const IN = N1 * (N2 - 2);
    // multiplied number
    const MN = IN + SN;
    console.log(N1, N2, SN, IN, MN);
}
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("submit", createVariables());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it. It won't create global variables, but if you really need global variables, you can modify to taste.

```js
//  DOM nodes to assist proof of concept
const input1   = document.getElementById('numberInput1');
const input2   = document.getElementById('numberInput2');
const output1  = document.querySelector('output[for="numberInput1"]');
const output2  = document.querySelector('output[for="numberInput2"]');
const outputSN = document.querySelector('output#sn');
const outputIN = document.querySelector('output#in');
const outputMN = document.querySelector('output#mn');

//  here is the meat of your logic
const recalculateDerivedValues = () => {
  const N1 = input1.valueAsNumber;
  const N2 = input2.valueAsNumber;
  const IN = N1 * (N2 - 2);
  const SN = N1 + (N2 - 1);
  outputSN.innerText = SN;
  outputIN.innerText = IN;
  outputMN.innerText = IN + SN;
};

//  attach event handlers so values are updated in real time
const watchThenUpdate = (watchedElement, updateElement) => {
  watchedElement.addEventListener('input', ev => {
    updateElement.innerText = ev.target.value;
    recalculateDerivedValues();
  });
};


//  attach event handlers to respective elements
watchThenUpdate(input1, output1);
watchThenUpdate(input2, output2);
```

```css
output {
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: maroon;
}

output::before {
  content: attr(id);
  padding-right: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="f" name="f">
  <label for="input number">Please enter two numbers:</label>
  <input type="number" name="input number 1" id="numberInput1" required>
  <input type="number" name="input number 2" id="numberInput2" required>
</form>

<output form="f" for="numberInput1" id="N1"></output>
<output form="f" for="numberInput2" id="N2"></output>

<output id="sn"></output>
<output id="in"></output>
<output id="mn"></output>
```